# map of a struct as a key and a vector of a struct as its value declaration

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, struct

I have a struct with two members an int and a string.

```
struct A
{
 int a;
 string b;
}

vector<A> pl;
pl = getPL(); //getPL returns a vector<A>
for ( auto: pl )
{
 vector<A>tr;
 tr = getTR() //getTR returns vector<A>
 for(auto: tr)
 {
  //store tr somewhere..
 } 

}
```

I want to create a `map<A, vector<A>>` so that each pl object can hold one vector. How to do that? Is there any other way or data structure in c++ that can achieve what I am trying to do.
Thanks,

Comment: `for ( auto: pl )` - that compiles? Also, I'm not really sure what your problem is. Why does `map<A, vector<A>>` not work for you?

Comment: I know that won't compile. it should be for(auto i: pl). I am actually looking for how to store the results in a map eg. map<A, vector<A>> something like that.

Comment: To use `A` as the key in a map, you will either need to define `operator <` for it or provide the map with a custom `key_compare` function.

Comment: @dlf I am actually new to c++, can you provide me with some syntax? Thanks.

Comment: @JosephMansfield Is making a map<A, vector<A>> a good idea? or is there any other way to implement the same? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map`s keep their data sorted by key. But to do this, they need some way to compare two key objects and determine which one should come first. By default, this comparison is done using the `<` operator, but that operation is not defined for `A`, which (probably) explains the compile error you are (probably) seeing.

So; to use `A` as the key in a `std::map`, you will either need to define `operator <` for it or provide the map with a custom `key_compare` functor. The code below demonstrates both approaches:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    int a;
    std::string b;
};

bool operator <(const A& l, const A& r)
{
    if(l.a != r.a)
        return l.a < r.a;
    return l.b < r.b;
}

struct B
{
    int a;
    std::string b;
};

struct CompareBs
{
    bool operator()(const B& l, const B& r) const
    {
        if(l.a != r.a)
            return l.a < r.a;
        return l.b < r.b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<A, std::vector<A>> aMap;
    std::map<B, std::vector<B>, CompareBs> bMap;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how to populate/fill in this map now? Thanks.